# How to block website for particular IPs through aws WAF

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, web-application-firewall, amazon-waf

I'm running a website `"www.example.com"` on **classic load balancer** and behind classic load balancer attached EC2 instances, and also using a cloudfront `assets.example.com` for static data.

I noticed in nginx access logs some IPs are scraping the data daily. So I want to block those IPs in AWS WAF rules. But WAF can be associated with: 1) CloudFront 2) API Gateway 3)Application Load Balancer.

I can block the IPs only for static data which goes through CloudFront.

Below is the nginx logs example:

```
10.0.0.1 "POST /candidate/Event_v3/eventRegistered
10.0.0.2 "GET /account/preference
```

How to block those IPs to not access the account, candidate etc sections?

Or how to block whole website `www.example.com` for particular IPs?

Can anyone help me out please.

Answer (score 1):

You have several options one would be a web application firewall like https://www.asp-waf.com that does that as well as a lot more... and always works

alternatively, You can use [ipsecurity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity/) if your IIS installation supports it.
or fixed set in web config

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="true">    
           <!-- block one set IP -->
           <add ipAddress="10.0.0.0" subnetMask="255.255.255.100"/>   
        </ipSecurity>
      </security>
      <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option to block the IP in this case is from the app itself. Add code to the app that returns a 403 or similar for a blacklist of ips you maintain in the app.

It would still reach the app, but normal service would be blocked.